# app rejected for using libsqlite3.dylib

Tags: iphone, app-store, submission

i am able to distribute and test my app using adhoc, but when i validate it for app store submission in organizer(xcode 4.3.2 - Product > Archive > Validate) i get the following error

- your app contains non public api usage
- the app references non public symbols in payload/appname.app/ libsqlite3.dylib:
  _dispatch_source_type_vm

my app uses sqlite3 for storing data got from youtube i.e video title and corresponding image url (max 10 records)

i have removed and added lib file,
set deployment target to 4.0,
please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got solution from Apple team

- Response from Apple(DTS - Developer Technical Support):

"You should only link to the libsqlite3.dylib library. You don't need to copy it into your app, because iOS ships with an SQLite3 library".

- Solution:

Remove libsqlite3.dylib from xcode and add '-libsqlite3' to "Other Linker Flags" under Project > Build Settings and Target > Build Settings.

---

The validation was successful and submitted the app to app store for review
...
Just updating FYI
The app got approved

Comment: Thx man! I have a app coming out in a few weeks and I have libsqlite3.dylib included. Knowing this will save me a rejection. So once again, thx!

Comment: you are welcome @MrDresden and good luck, i felt the following link useful before submitting the app to appstore for review 
See [this](http://www.makayama.com/checklist.html)

Answer (score 4):

The correct flag should be '-lsqlite3' as the ls syntax is (see $man ld):

-lx This option tells the linker to search for libx.dylib or libx.a in the library search path.  If string x is of the form y.o, then that file is searched for in the same places,                 **but without prepending `lib' or appending`.a' or `.dylib' to the filename**.

If you use '-libsqlite3' for the flag you get the "Library not found" linker error.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue.